# nested object in a class Python

Tags: python, oop, object, nested

I am obviously missing something fundamental here. Hopefully someone can put me right! TIA

I have an array of objects whose class contains instances of another object. But when I set a property for one of these then they all change.

```
class direction():
    dest = -1
    lock = ''
class room():
    roomname = ''
    desc = ''
    n = direction()
    s = direction()
    w = direction()
    e = direction()
    item = ''

rooms = []
rooms.append( room() )
rooms.append( room() )
rooms.append( room() )
rooms.append( room() )
rooms.append( room() )

rooms[0].roomname = 'outside'
rooms[0].desc = ''
rooms[0].n.dest = 4
rooms[0].item = ''

rooms[1].roomname = 'hall'
rooms[1].desc = 'The hallway has doors to the east and south'
rooms[1].n.dest = 2
rooms[1].item = ''
```

if I iterate through the n.dest properties in the rooms list then all are returned as 2

It is as if the direction objects in each object in the rooms list are all a single instance and setting one value in one of them sets it for all of them.

Comment: BTW please ignore the lack of constructors - I am keeping the code simple just now and will add them later.

Comment: The lack of constructors *is* the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attributes are all declared at class level, not instance level, meaning that every instance of the class will share the same values. I think you want:

```py
class Room():
    def __init__(self):
        self.roomname = ''
        self.desc = ''
        self.n = direction()
        self.s = direction()
        self.w = direction()
        self.e = direction()
        self.item = ''
```

Comment: Thank you, that works - but I have no idea why. I will now look up the difference between class and instance level...

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3

I understand now. Thank you.

Comment: BUT what I don't now understand is WHY do my rooms all retain different roomname properties etc and it is only the nested class which is affected?

Comment: When you do `rooms[1].roomname = 'hall` you create a new instance attribute that will shadow the class atrribute. With `rooms[1].n.dest = 2` you set a new value for the attribute `dest`, but this attribute belongs to an existing class level attribute `n`.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing constructors, and therefore missing instance variables

You're defining class variables, so each variable is the same between all instances

Answer (score 0):

In each class, you have declared a bunch of *class* attributes. An assignment like  `rooms[0].roomname = 'outside'` creates an *instance* attribute that shadows `room.roomname`. However, you never actually make any such assignment to `rooms[0].n`, so each assignment to something like `rooms[0].n.dest` is adding an instance attribute `dest` to the *same* instance of `direction` shared by each instance of `room`.

In your attempt to "simplify" your code, you've made it more complicated. Define `__init__` to set your *instance* attributes; class attributes are not used as often.

```
class Direction:
    def __init__(self, dest, lock=''):
        self.dest = dest
        self.lock = lock

class Room:
    def __init__(self, roomname, desc, item=''):
        self.roomname = roomname
        self.desc = desc
        self.n = direction()
        self.s = direction()
        self.w = direction()
        self.e = direction()
        self.item = item


rooms = []
r = Room('outside', '')
r.n.dest = 4
rooms.append(r)


r = Room('hall', 'The hallway has doors to the east and south')
r.n.dest = 2
rooms.append(r)
```

Comment: Thank you that makes sense now. I've just had a crash course on class and instance attributes!